# How to add checkboxes under one group in GWT?

Tags: java, gwt, checkbox

I am currently working on GWT.
I am stuck with CheckBoxGroup ..
how can I gropu my checkboxes under one name?
like in java i can use

```
 CheckboxGroup entreeGroup = new CheckboxGroup();
```

and then add.()..

but in GWT add() is not there..

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GWT generates Javascript which in turn produces HTML. In HTML, to group checkboxes together, you simply set the same name on all of them. GWT uses the same technique.

Use `getElement().setAttribute("name","your_checkbox_group_name");` on all your checkboxes. http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.4/com/google/gwt/dom/client/Element.html#setAttribute(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)

There may be some code that does the same but I am unaware of it.

EDIT:

As mentionned by Ganesh Kumar, if what you expect is to have only a single checkbox selected at a time, then you are looking for [RadionButtons](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.4/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/RadioButton.html). They take a "name" argument in their constructor in order to identify a same group of RadioButtons

Comment: I think the intention is to use check boxes with the functionality of radio buttons. Setting the same name for a set of check boxes does not restrict the user to select only one of the check boxes, instead user can select one or more of the boxes.

Comment: @GaneshKumar Yes that was my thinking too, but the OP talked about CheckBoxes. I updated my post to make that very valid remark.

Comment: that was really helpful thanks.. :) what i did ..i created List for the each item...before your suggestion..
but getelement.setAttribute() is waorking absolutely fine.. :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, if check box is limited to a specific functionality, and later you want to do some sort of processing in those check boxes together, I used ArrayList of CheckBox, and added checkboxes in this list at time of checkbox creation. Later I will just run through this list and get selected checkboxes or do some sort of processing. Hope this helps.